# Blazor 6.0 Publish doesn't produce the index.html file

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have written something using blazor wasm and am trying to publish the project on Github Pages. However, when I try the `dotnet publish -c Release` command, it only produces a list of files as followed:

1. *wwwroot* folder containing all the static sources but without an *index.html* file
2. the *.json*, *.dll*, *web.config* and an *.exe* file.

Generally, if I want to upload the page to Github Pages, I would need an *index.html* file which would be automatically generated by blazor publish I believe, but there isnt.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does your project's wwwroot folder have the index.html file?

Comment: neither does my publish folder nor project folder has an index.html file

Comment: You'll need to manually create the index.html file in your project's wwwroot folder. I'm not sure why it isn't there - it's necessary to run the application. Did you delete it by accident?

Comment: Well I believe I just accidentally deleted that cuz I'm new to blazor... Should I do any configurations to this index.html file once I've added it?

Comment: There should be a  `index.html` file and no `web.config` . It looks like you have a Blazor server project, or converted something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project's wwwroot folder needs to contain an index.html file. That's what gets initially served to the browser and is the root of all other file requests (images, dlls, etc). Unlike a web.config file (used for IIS), this file is *NOT* generated for you - you maintain the file.

You can always create a new Blazor WebAssembly project to get an example of what the index.html file should look like, but this is the current template file at time of writing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp1</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can customize it yourself afterwards to fit your needs. Note that the `<div id="app">` is where your app get injected into, unless you customize it.

Simply putting this file in the project's wwwroot folder will have it copied to the published directory's wwwroot folder during compilation.